# how to randomly split the data in a two dimensional array and display them in a 75% and 25% format

Tags: java, arrays

I loaded a two dimensional array from a txt file. I need the program to randomly display 75% and 25% of the array separately. I tried using Math.random but it change the numbers to display from 0 to 1. I will be using the numbers in further calculations. I have enclosed the whole code. The dataSplit method is where I separate the array. The txt file that I am using in this example is for testing purposes only. I actually have a much larger file.

Thank you in advance for your help,
Avi

p.s. I am starting the column count from 1 because column 1 is to be ignored.

This is the txt file

1 6 7 8

2 9 10 11

3 12 13 14

Below is the code

```
package tester;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{      
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("one.txt"));

    float [][] glassdata = new float[3][4];

    loadArray(glassdata, inFile);
    displayArray(glassdata);

    System.out.println("\n***************\n");

    normalizingVector(glassdata);

    System.out.println("\n***************\n");

    dataSplit(glassdata);
}

public static void loadArray(float [][] g, Scanner inFile)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < g[row].length; col++)
        {
           g[row][col] = inFile.nextFloat();
        }
    }      
}

public static void displayArray(float [][] g)   
{
    for(int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < g[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(g[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void normalizingVector(float [][] g)
{
    float temp1 = 0;
    float temp2 = 0;        

    for (int row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 1; col < g[row].length; col++)
        {               
            while(col < g[row].length)              
            {
                temp1 = temp1 + (float) Math.pow(g[row][col], 2);
                col++;
            }

            col = 1;
            temp1 = (float) Math.sqrt(temp1);

            while(col < g[row].length)
            {               
                temp2 = (g[row][col]) / temp1;
                System.out.print(temp2 + " ");
                col++;              
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        temp1 = 0;
        temp2 = 0;
    }
}

public static void dataSplit(float [][] g)
{
    int row;
    int col;
    for(row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(col = 1; col < g[row].length * 0.75; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(g[row][col] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("*******!@#$$*************");

    for(row = 0; row < g.length; row++)
    {
        for(col = 2; col < g[row].length * 0.25; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(g[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add a language tag.

Comment: *"I loaded a two dimensional array from a txt file. I need the program to randomly display 75% and 25% of the array separately. "* ... try as I might to discern meaning from your description, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: What I trying to do is randomly pick out 75% of the data and display, and then display the remaining 25% of the data